# EntityFramework - ApplicationUser as Foreign Key causing error with Roles and Logins

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an artist class which I am trying to form a one-to-one relationship with AspNetUser. I want to use the Id of AspNetUser as a foreign key in my Artist model.
Artist :

```
public class Artist
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("ApplicationUser")]
    public string ArtistId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

IdentityModels.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

    public virtual Artist Artist { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

But I am getting this error :
[image]

Why is error being caused? Using code first with entity framework.

Comment: What does your DbContext type look like?  The error references entities you have not posted.

Comment: I added it @DavidBrowne-Microsoft

Comment: I'm really new to asp.net btw